# format datetime based on users culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, formatting

How can I format the date and time depending on the users region settings in an `ASP.NET-MVC` application without worrying about the order of the date?

For example, I want to have:

1. the day with a leading zero (dd);
2. month abbreviated three-letter form (MMM);
3. full year (yyyy);
4. the time just the hours and minutes both with leading zeros (HH:mm);
5. depending on if the user is from USA show AM/PM after the time;

Every country displays the date in a different order. USA displays first the month than days than years (MMM/dd/yyyy). In China first the year than month than day (yyyy-MMM-dd) (IIRC). And in Europe most countries display the date in this format: dd-MMM-yyyy.

And then not to mention the slashes/dashes used to separate the month, days and years from each other in every country.

This of course can be done with an endless `if`/`else` or `switch` statement, but isn't there a more elegant way to do this?

**EDIT** this is the best I came up with:

```
var cltr = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
DateTime.Now.ToString(cltr.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern + " " + cltr.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern)
```

It displays the date in numbers only. How would I change that in short month notation but not changing the order and the separators etc?

Comment: When it's "depending on the users region settings" you don't get to pick leading zeroes or 12/24 hr formats.

Comment: Looking at the bigger picture (thus apart from what I get to choose or not), have you got an idea how I could do this?

Comment: @Quoter But that is the bigger picture, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the culture currently used by the user with CurrentCulture and CurrentCultureInfo.

For more details, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about formatting issue. Once you have your `DateTime` object, then you can display it as you want. You have to specify `new CultureInfo("en-US")` as `IFormatProvider` in the `DateTime.ToString()` method if you want to show the datetime as US format.

Comment: I knew that one, just don't want to do this like a few 100 times. So is there a way to automate the `new CultureInfo("en-US")` process instead of using countless `if`/`else` statements?